# Boxplot does not appear properly

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to compare different Machine learning algorithms. I used Box graph to do the comparison. Yet, the graph does not show a proper results. This is the code:

```
results = []
names = []
for name, model in models:
    kfold = KFold(n_splits=4, random_state=1, shuffle=True)
    cv_results = cross_val_score(model, X_train, Y_train, cv=kfold, scoring='accuracy')
    results.append(cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    print('%s: %f (%f)' % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std()))

# Compare Algorithms

pyplot.xticks(range(1,9),labels=names,rotation=40,ha='right')
pyplot.boxplot(results, labels=names)
pyplot.title('Algorithm Comparison')
pyplot.ylabel(("Accuracy"))
pyplot.show()
```

result output:

```
LDA: 0.769728 (0.008044)
KNN: 1.000000 (0.000000)
Random Forset: 1.000000 (0.000000)
CART: 1.000000 (0.000000)
NB: 0.514771 (0.004631)
SVM: 1.000000 (0.000000)
```

Can anyone see what I did wrong so I can fix it.
[image: plot]

Comment: What results do you expect? What is the difference between the two images you attached? It looks fine to me.

Comment: Hi @Solvalou, I am new to boxplot and I just saw line. I cannot see the upper and lower quartiles. Basically, the two images are the same.

Comment: Take a look at your output. Some of these models have a standard deviation of 0. This means that the mean and standard deviation were probably calculated from just a single point. Since there is no distribution in the end, this also means there is no standard deviation and there are no quartiles. Therefore, you end up with a single line in your plot, representing just the mean.

Comment: @Solvalou, thank you very much for your great explanation. I really appreciate it. Now I have a clear understanding of the boxplot. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome! I transformed my comment into an answer so also others can find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The box plot is behaving like it is expected.
Please take a look at your output. Some of these models have a standard deviation of 0. This means that the mean and standard deviation were probably calculated from just a single point. Since there is no distribution in the end, this also means there is no standard deviation and there are no quartiles. Therefore, you end up with a single line in your plot, representing just the mean.